# Best practice for package install on Django server

Tags: python, django, nginx, server

So I'm setting up a server by myself. Now I ran into lots of different ways where to install the packages.
I am thinking of the core packages like nginx, gunicorn, python3, PostgreSQL and so on.

I learned that setting up a VENV (virtual environment) is a good thing so I can have several projects running with different versions on packages.

But it's a bit confusing which ones are not going to be inside the VENV.

Some install PostgreSQL outside the VENV, but psycopg2 inside. Some the gunicorn inside VENV. and so on.

***Are there any best practices or rules that are better safe to follow?***

For info. I'm setting up a Ubuntu server 16.04 with Nginx, gunicorn. PostgreSQL, psycopg2, python3

Comment: postgreSQL isn't a python package, so you can't install it in the virtual environment. Usually you would use your package manager (i.e. `apt` in Ubuntu) to install it.

Comment: Ahh. so a virtual environment is only a virtual for python packages. I was so stuck in my mind venv being like a virtual machine. Got it. All python packages inside the VENV and everything outside. Thanks! I'm new to all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what I use for my applications, it's working but maybe there are better options.

- Nginx, PostgreSQL, python3, supervisor installed as system packages
- Using virtualenv for each of the applications I run inside one server
  and I install there: gunicorn, psycopg2 and all other requirements
  for Django project (Most of the time it's listed inside
  `requirements.txt` file)
- Using supervisor to run gunicorn and Celery(When needed)

If you want to make some server installation automation you can use [Ansible](https://github.com/jcalazan/ansible-django-stack), it's not that complex and interface well with Python/Django with plenty of code examples. But it's better that you start doing things on your own at first to know and understand what you're doing.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

@Mounir's answer is pretty solid- but I wanted to tag on another piece of advice- using playbooks from Ansible Galaxy is also another option.  Existing playbooks already exist for lots of usecases (including Django) and they take into account many of these best practices.  I am not saying that all playbooks on Galaxy are good- but some are, and by virtue of being open source, they are frequently patched and updated.